# How to compile a device driver into the kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, compilation, kernel, driver

I have a PC and I have NIC. I run on Rocky Linux and the NIC is [D-Link DFE-530TX](https://eu.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DFE/DFE%20530TXplus/Manual/DFE%20530TX_Manual_EN_UK.pdf)

This is the driver I found:
http://www.opendrivers.com/download/driver-118312.html

In the `/LINUX` directory after unpacking there is a good `linux.txt` file that states the following.

```
Kernel Supported
================
    This driver supports linux kernel version 2.2.x, 2.4.x and 2.6.x now.
    For 2.6 kernel, it supported up to 2.6.18 in this version.
```

The full TxT file can be read here (for a year from now): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cVbJ2BqJvG/

My out-of-the-box Rocky 8.6 comes like this:

```
Operating System: Rocky Linux 8.6 (Green Obsidian)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:rocky:rocky:8:GA
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

My question would be It is possible to compile the driver ? If the answer is `yes` than I would ask how I need to compile it ?

**My expection is somebody will be able to explain to me the essence of the activity or be able to share a good step-by-step from which I can learn it by myself.**

(*I red a lot and tried in many ways without success. It fails with on the most different ways.*)

Mentioned `/LINUX` directory contains a `Makefile` but `make` command fails if I enter.

`Makefile:70: *** Linux kernel source not configured - missing version.h. Stop.`

```
[root@iredmail LINUX]# find / -name version.h
    /root/build/kernel/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
    /usr/include/lzma/version.h
    /usr/include/elfutils/version.h
    /usr/include/linux/dvb/version.h
    /usr/include/linux/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/config/clang/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/config/gcc/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/linux/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
    /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64/include/xen/interface/version.h
```

P.S. I know there is VIA support in the kernel. Compiling a kernel takes hours and I expect compile only a driver into a ready kernel takes significantly less time. But I don't know how I need to do.

P.S.2 I am interested in any solution that avoids compiling the whole kernel. Thank you in advance.

**Appendix - content of Makefile**

```
DEBUG = 0

KSP :=  /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build \
    /usr/src/linux-$(shell uname -r) \
    /usr/src/linux-$(shell uname -r | sed 's/-.*//') \
    /usr/src/kernel-headers-$(shell uname -r) \
    /usr/src/kernel-source-$(shell uname -r) \
    /usr/src/linux-$(shell uname -r | sed 's/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\..*/\1/') \
    /usr/src/linux

test_dir = $(shell [ -e $(dir)/include/linux ] && echo $(dir))
KSP := $(foreach dir, $(KSP), $(test_dir))

KSRC := $(firstword $(KSP))
ifeq (,$(KSRC))
  $(error Linux kernel source not found)
endif

# check kernel version
KVER := $(shell uname -r | cut -c1-3 | sed 's/2\.[56]/2\.6/')
KERVER2=$(shell uname -r | cut -d. -f2)

ifeq ($(KVER), 2.6)
  # 2.6 kernel
  TARGET = rhinefet.ko
  BUILTIN = via-rhine.ko
else
  TARGET = rhinefet.o
  BUILTIN = via-rhine.o
endif

INSTDIR := $(shell find /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r) -name $(TARGET) -printf "%h\n" | sort | head -1)
ifeq (,$(INSTDIR))
        ifeq (,$(KERVER2))
                ifneq (,$(wildcard /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel))
                        INSTDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net
                else
                        INSTDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/net
                endif
        else
                ifneq ($(KERVER2),2)
                        INSTDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net
                else
                        INSTDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/net
                endif
        endif
endif

SRC = rhine_main.c rhine_proc.c rhine_wol.c rhine_hw.c

# build rule
ifeq ($(KVER), 2.6)
# 2.6 kernel

obj-m += rhinefet.o
rhinefet-objs := rhine_main.o rhine_proc.o rhine_wol.o rhine_hw.o

default:
    make -C $(KSRC) SUBDIRS=$(shell pwd) modules

else
# 2.2/2.4 kernel

OBJS := rhine_main.o rhine_proc.o rhine_wol.o rhine_hw.o

VERSION_FILE := $(KSRC)/include/linux/version.h
CONFIG_FILE  := $(KSRC)/include/linux/config.h

ifeq (,$(wildcard $(VERSION_FILE)))
  $(error Linux kernel source not configured - missing version.h)
endif

ifeq (,$(wildcard $(CONFIG_FILE)))
  $(error Linux kernel source not configured - missing config.h)
endif

ifneq (,$(findstring egcs-2.91.66, $(shell cat /proc/version)))
  CC := kgcc gcc cc
else
  CC := gcc cc
endif

test_cc = $(shell which $(cc) > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo $(cc))
CC := $(foreach cc, $(CC), $(test_cc))
CC := $(firstword $(CC))

CFLAGS += -Wall -DLINUX -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DEXPORT_SYMTAB -D__NO_VERSION__ -O2 -pipe
CFLAGS += -I$(KSRC)/include -I. -Wstrict-prototypes -fomit-frame-pointer
CFLAGS += $(shell [ -f $(KSRC)/include/linux/modversions.h ] && \
            echo "-DMODVERSIONS -include $(KSRC)/include/linux/modversions.h")

.SILENT: $(TARGET) clean

# look for SMP in config.h
SMP := $(shell $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E -dM $(CONFIG_FILE) | \
    grep CONFIG_SMP | awk '{ print $$3 }')

ifneq ($(SMP),1)
  SMP := 0
endif

ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
  CFLAGS += -DRHINE_DBG
endif

ifeq ($(SMP), 1)
  CFLAGS += -D__SMP__
endif

# check x86_64
SUBARCH := $(shell uname -m)
ifeq ($(SUBARCH),x86_64)
  CFLAGS += -mcmodel=kernel -mno-red-zone
endif

$(TARGET): $(filter-out $(TARGET), $(SRC:.c=.o))
    $(LD) -r $^ -o $@
    echo; echo
    echo "**************************************************"
    echo "Build options:"
    echo "   VERSION    $(shell uname -r)"
    echo -n "   SMP        "
    if [ "$(SMP)" = "1" ]; \
        then echo "Enabled"; else echo "Disabled"; fi
    echo "**************************************************"

endif # ifeq ($(KVER),2.6)

ifeq ($(KVER), 2.6)
  install: default
else
  install: clean $(TARGET)
endif
    mkdir -p $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)
    install -m 644 -o root $(TARGET) $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)
    @if [ -f $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN) ] ; then \
        echo "*****  Move official driver $(BUILTIN) to $(BUILTIN).backup file" ; \
        echo "mv $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN) $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN).backup";\
        mv $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN) $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN).backup ; \
        echo ;\
    fi ;
    @if [ -f $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/linuxfet.o ] ; then \
        echo "*****  Move previous driver linuxfet.o to linuxfet.o.backup" ; \
        echo "mv $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/linuxfet.o $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/linuxfet.o.backup";\
        mv $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/linuxfet.o $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/linuxfet.o.backup ; \
        echo ;\
    fi ;

ifeq (,$(MOD_ROOT))
    /sbin/depmod -a || true
else
    /sbin/depmod -b $(MOD_ROOT) -a || true
endif

uninstall:
    rm -f $(INSTDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @if [ -f $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN).backup ] ; then \
        echo "*****  Restore official driver $(BUILTIN) from $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)".; \
        echo "mv $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN).backup $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN)";\
        mv $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN).backup $(MOD_ROOT)$(INSTDIR)/$(BUILTIN) ;\
    fi
    /sbin/depmod -a

clean:
    rm -f $(SRC:.c=.o) rhinefet.o rhinefet.ko rhinefet.mod.c rhinefet.mod.o *~
```

If I need to add anything to this question please comment it.

Comment: "My expection is somebody will be able to explain to me the essence of the activity .." - Tthe possible activity path is: 1. Understand Makefile. 2. Adapt it for the new kernel version (or remove all `if`s except the one suitable for your system). 3. Understand the driver's sources. 4. Adapt them to the new kernel version. Even for a person who understand the Linux kernel well this could be challenging. As for one who is not familiar with the Linux kernel... Well, recompiling a full kernel in several hours would be faster in many times.

Comment: Seriously, your question can only be "answered" by writing the **whole code** for you. Which is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: I started to compile the kernel. I was just disappointed that I cannot compile only the driver. I cannot accept the fact that something is so difficult to understand. I mean I can create a simple Makefile but it doesn't work. Why? What I supposed to learn or understand to be able to add a simple network card to a modern linux kernel ?

Comment: `make` was continuously complaining about missing header (.h) files. I found all the 'missing' files and solved the errors by using symbolic links. Finally `make` and `make install` were able to finish but returned with `Error 1`. Expected result `rhinefet.o` file wasn't created.

Comment: _Compiling a kernel takes hours_... No it's not! Just built latest master from scratch for `x86_64_defconfig` target on my laptop and it took: `4m22.443s`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I need to know how you did that. My latest compile took 11 hours. (Intel Celeron D 352 1socket/1core 3.20GHz // 2GB DDR2 RAM) followed this document: https://docs.rockylinux.org/en/guides/custom-linux-kernel/

Comment: `time make x86_64_defconfig`, and then `time make -j${nproc}`. I'm using HP EliteBook 850 G8 with 16GB and i7 8-core CPU, with installed Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs `VIA Support` option can be found in the `menuconfig` . I enabled it as `kernel module` and started to compile the kernel. It was successful. It took 783 minutes. After booting the new kernel I was able to enable the NIC. But I still don't understand how I can simple 'enable' this 'VIA support' without compiling the whole kernel. What commands do I need to enter ? (I also tried to compile the driver from the source code but that's far more difficult. I guess that's not the way how it should work.) How the experts do this ?

Comment: Well, first of all - compiling kernel in 783 minutes - that's incredible. Do you use VM, or building on native Linux machine? As to how I would do it - build your driver as a module vs your current kernel. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Thank you for your help again. Yes indedd 700+ minutes is horror. This is a physical computer but pretty old. Check this photo: https://ibb.co/hZWLNbv

Comment: @supi007 I will try to find some time in the upcoming days and will follow the steps on the link you've provided, just out of curiosity. Want to measure the time on exact same build. Will come back later with my results.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I've understood why the compile takes so long. This article https://docs.rockylinux.org/en/guides/custom-linux-kernel/ describes a complete kernel compile. It uses the `.config` file of the current factory kernel which is pretty large because contains pretty much unnecessary entities. The cure was the `make localmodconfig`. With this option I could create a significantly smaller kernel config that decrased the time of compile on an old and slow computer with 1 CPU and 2GB of RAM. It took less than 2 hours. (I forgot to start `time`).

Comment: @supi007 Ok, glad you found this. Of course, you don't need all of the options kernel provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you will not be able to build a driver which is supported up to 2.6.18 and your kernel is 4.18.

Good news is that this NIC has upstream Linux driver for quite some time now, [look here at the source of 4.18](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/drivers/net/ethernet/dlink/sundance.c#L225). As per [Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/drivers/net/ethernet/dlink/Makefile), it is enabled via `CONFIG_SUNDANCE`. So I believe this NIC should work out of the box.

If not, you might want to build just this driver as a module for your current kernel. How to do that - this falls out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I try all you mentioned and I can imagine that I will try to build the driver as a module. Do you have any material (some kind of useable blog article, recommendation, standard) that I could use to understand how to do that ? Just a clue, a push to the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Here, check first answer to the first question: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelCustomBuild

Comment: Please note, however - unless you manually setup `dkms` for this driver, you will need to rebuild your module every time you upgrade kernel on your machine.